# Camera does not set Image on ImageView

Tags: android, android-logcat, android-camera-intent

The ImageView returns blank when I try to set an Image from a Camera to an Image view. I have given permissions in the Manifest and everything. It still doesn't work. I've been stuck with this since the past week. Please Help. Here is the code:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
    static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;
    String mCurrentPhotoPath;
    ImageView mImageView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                dispatchTakePictureIntent();
            }
        });
    }


        private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
            // Create an image file name
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
            String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
            File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            File image = File.createTempFile(
                    imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                    ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                    storageDir      /* directory */
            );

            // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
            mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
            Log.d("","file place:"+mCurrentPhotoPath);
            return image;
        }
    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File

            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
            }
        }
    }

    public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(String path,
                                                     int reqWidth, int reqHeight) { // BEST QUALITY MATCH

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight) {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
        }

        int expectedWidth = width / inSampleSize;

        if (expectedWidth > reqWidth) {
            //if(Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth) > inSampleSize) // If bigger SampSize..
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
        }


        options.inSampleSize = inSampleSize;

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        //setPic();
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator + "image.jpg");
        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), 500, 250));
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
11-30 11:30:12.479 11680-11680/com.example.samarth.cameraimagecapture E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.samarth.cameraimagecapture/com.example.samarth.cameraimagecapture.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.example.samarth.cameraimagecapture/com.example.samarth.cameraimagecapture.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2458)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2486)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2000)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.example.samarth.cameraimagecapture/com.example.samarth.cameraimagecapture.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2997)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2445)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2486) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2000) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.io.File.fixSlashes(File.java:185)
at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:134)
at com.example.samarth.cameraimagecapture.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:175)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4654)
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2993)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2445) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2486) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2000) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I think you are getting wrong image from onActivityResult, and you  created imageFile is different

Comment: @sam24 Have you add  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> ` these permission in `AndroidManifest.xml` file?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to

**onActivityResult**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    //setPic();
  if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO){
    Log.d("onActivityResult","file place:"+mCurrentPhotoPath);
    mImageView.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, 500, 250));
  }
}
```

**createImageFile**

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        Log.d("","file place:"+mCurrentPhotoPath);
        return image;
    }
```

Comment: I get this error: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.example.samarth.cameraimagecapture/com.example.samarth.cameraimagecapture.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: I still get this error. What can I do to rectify it?

Comment: If the error still exist, can you post your logcat?

Comment: Please check the EDIT

Comment: I have updated the code.. But can you tell me which android os you are using to run the app?

Comment: Android version is 4.0.4

Comment: Now, nothing is visible on the image view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96520/discussion-between-fabin-paul-and-sam24).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the problem. When you dispatch the intent to fetch the picture, you're providing a Uri to write the image to.

```
takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
```

**However**, in the `onActivityResult` method, you're creating a brand new file (which will be empty) and setting the ImageView object to the bitmap extracted from that file.

Here's how you can fix this.

1) Use the file you passed to the intent

```
// Make this a class variable
File photoFile;

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File

            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
            }
        }
    }
```

And then in the `onActivityResult` method:

```
mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
mImageView.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(photoFile.getAbsolutePath(), 500, 250));
```

Instead of saving the file, you could also save just the filepath and reinitialize the file in `onActivityResult`

2) Alternatively, if all you want to do is set the result to an imageView, I'd recommend:

remove this line

```
takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
```

And in `onActivityResult`:

```
if (result == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
    mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    // data.getData() will return the bitmap
    mImageView.setImageBitmap(data.getData());
}
```

Please note that you should really check `(requestCode == TAKE_PHOTO_REQUEST)`, before doing the rest, because you want to make sure it's a response to your request to take a photo

Comment: I get this error: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.example.samarth.cameraimagecapture/com.example.samarth.cameraimagecapture.M‌​ainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

```
String imageFileName,imagePath;

private void clickPhotoFromCamera() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
            imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg";
            File imageStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), imageFileName);
            uri = Uri.fromFile(imageStorageDir);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

        }

    @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (requestCode == 1) {
                    imagePath = uri.getPath();
                    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath.getAbsolutePath());
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
                }
            }
        }
```